# Getting empty list while using xpath with html.fromstring

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests, lxml.html

I am trying to extract text from a webpage using below code. It is working fine for other websites but here i am getting empty list

```
import requests
from lxml import html

siteurl = 'https://clinicaltrials.gov/ct2/show/NCT03752268?cond=cancer&draw=2&rank=1'
rq = requests.get(siteurl)
get_soup = html.fromstring(rq.content)
name = get_soup.xpath('//*[@id="tab-body"]/div/div[7]/div[2]/div[3]/table/tbody/tr/td[1]//text()')
print(name)
```

Comment: what do you expect to print?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this xpath:

`//td[@headers="contactName"]//text()`

and for future, try to create a more readable "xpath" than picking the one from browser dev tools.

Answer (score 0):

Consider also using css attribute = value selector. This is both shorter so less fragile, quicker as stops at the first match, and by adding/removing the `i` you can make case insensitive/sensitive

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

r = requests.get('https://clinicaltrials.gov/ct2/show/NCT03752268?cond=cancer&draw=2')
soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml')
print(soup.select_one('[headers=contactName i]').text)
```